# how to convert my sql query into json using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have created a text box in which a query is entered and I need to run the query to display the values stored in the mysql table using php. Kindly help me with the approach of the project or any links that can help me. I have tried doing it by taking single query in php:

```
<?php
    $username = "username"; 
    $password = "password";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="test";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
    $myquery = "SELECT  `date_joined`, `city` FROM  `users`";

    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    mysql_close($server);

?>
```

But I want to get the json for every query that is being entered in the textbox. How do I handle that ?

Comment: Can you share an example of the JSON you're getting and the JSON you'd like to get for that data?

Comment: Hii this code is perfectly fine and generates json according to the requirement , my issue is i have actually entered a static query and it returned me a json i require how do i make it work dynamically like if i enter any query in my textbox in html form that should call this php file and execute the query which i entered in the text box and give me a json output .

Comment: Then your problem is not "convert a SQL query into JSON" - you've got that covered. Your problem is "execute a query passed through a TEXTAREA". You need a HTML FORM for that, a `$myquery = $_POST['textfieldname']` somewhere, error checking and limit access to non-malicious users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="test";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
$myquery = "";

$myquery = $_POST["id_of_the_text_box"];
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);

?>
```

But try to validate first the SQL entered in the textfield.